# Does kubernetes have an equivalent to docker commit/save

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

I'm working on a system that spins up pods in k8s for user to work in for a while.  They'll be running code, modifying files, etc.  One thing I'd like to do is be able to effectively "export" their pod in it's modified state.  In docker I'd just `docker commit && docker save` to bundle it all to a tar, but I can't see anything at all similar in the kubernetes api, kubectl, nor client libs.

Comment: If you have three replicas of a Deployment, which one will you use?  How do you guarantee they have the same code?  If one breaks, how do you know what code is in it?  What if a node becomes unavailable; how will you get your images on to the new node?  (I generally recommend to never use `docker commit` at all; instead, set up a CI system to build images from source control, and you can point a Deployment at a specific build's image.)

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you deploy your cluster?

Comment: kubernetes orchestrates containers, it does not create or modify them.

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak k8s v1.18.15 and we are using Tanzu for the cluster management.

Comment: I do understand this is not a normal use case for k8s.  I'm more wondering if it's possible.  "No" is a fine answer if that's true.  Just the back of my head things SOMETHING must be able to do it even if it's interfacing with the CRI

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer: No, Kubernetes doesn't have an equivalent to docker commit/save.**

As [Markus Dresch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9423721/markus-dresch) mentioned in the comment:

> kubernetes orchestrates containers, it does not create or modify them.

Kubernetes and Docker are 2 different tools for different purposes.
Kubernetes, also known as K8s, is an open-source system for automating deployment, scaling, and management of containerized applications.

Docker is a set of platform as a service products that use OS-level virtualization to deliver software in packages called containers.

You can find more information about Pull, Edit, and Push a Docker Image [here](https://blog.macstadium.com/blog/how-to-k8s-pull-edit-and-push-a-docker-image).